# Swift "where" key word

Tags: swift, switch-statement

Disclaimer: swift noob

Hi, I've just begun going learning Swift and was going through The Swift Programming Language (Apple's book released during WWDC) and was wondering what the 'where' keyword is. It was used in

```
let vegetable = "red pepper"
switch vegetable {
case "celery":
    let vegetableComment = "Add some raisins and make ants on a log."
case "cucumber", "watercress":
    let vegetableComment = "That would make a good tea sandwich."
case let x where x.hasSuffix("pepper"):
    let vegetableComment = "Is it a spicy \(x)?"
default:
    let vegetableComment = "Everything tastes good in soup."
}
```

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language.” iBooks. https://itun.es/us/jEUH0.l

If anyone could explain and/or show the equivalent in another language (java, c++, obj-c, etc.) that would be great.

Apologies if this has already been asked, I didn't see it anywhere.

Comment: This information is available in the basic language guide. https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH9-XID_199

Comment: I don't think the languages you mentioned have a direct equivalent (short of manually constructing `if` statements). Scala has some similar in its pattern matching.

Comment: I don't think people should down-vote this question into oblivion, however, @Alex, you really should've just read the docs.

Comment: @theMonster that's probably true but still I still think it was a fair question. Most people will google a question they have before immediately consulting the documentation. Also the documentation page wasn't even on the first page of a google search so even if I do get downvoted, hopefully this will help others.

Comment: @Alex agreed, since `where` is already in a lot of other languages, I'm sure it's already google search-able. That said, this is still a very relevant question and shouldn't be down-voted.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Swift's `switch` statements are much more powerful than the ones used in most other languages. Instead of simply choosing from a group of values, they use pattern-matching to select which `case`  to evaluate. Let's look at each `case` from your example:

```
case "celery":
```

Super simple -- this will match the string `"celery"` and nothing else.

```
case "cucumber", "watercress":
```

This case will match *either* the string `"cucumber"` or the string `"watercress"`. Cool. In other languages you'd probably need to use a fallthrough case to get both of these.

```
case let x where x.hasSuffix("pepper"):
```

This case contains two concepts that are particular to Swift `switch` statements, when compared to Java and C. The first is value-binding -- the `let x` part of this statement binds the matched value to a constant `x` that is scoped to the case's body.

Next is the `where` clause. This is a boolean test, just like an `if` statement, so the case only matches if the expression is `true`. In this example, `x.hasSuffix("pepper")` looks at the bound value and checks to see if it ends with `"pepper"`. The strings `"red pepper"`, `"green pepper"`, and `"spicy hot pepper"` would all match, but `"peppercorns"` would not.

```
default:
```

In Swift, `switch` statements need to exhaust all the possible values of the matched value, so they typically end with a `default:` case block to handle any value that wasn't previously matched. The only time you wouldn't see this is if you're matching an `enum` with only a few values, since you could manually exhaust all the options.

Answer (score 16):

You can include multiple optional bindings in a single if statement and use a where clause to check for a Boolean condition:

```
if let firstNumber = Int("4"), secondNumber = Int("42") where firstNumber < secondNumber {
    print("\(firstNumber) < \(secondNumber)")
}
// prints "4 < 42
```

Comment: Great! It provides a init space and let the condition to be semantic.

Comment: [`where` clauses are no longer used like that in Swift 3](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0099-conditionclauses.md), just replace `where` with a comma instead.